# calculate time difference in group made from multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, difference

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  user       datetime              mode
    -------------------------------------------------
    1        2015-09-10 11:50:27        vehicle
    1        2015-11-22 10:15:03        vehicle
    1        2015-11-23 10:35:03        stop
    2        2015-11-22 10:11:13         walk
    2        2015-11-22 10:13:08         walk
    2        2015-09-10 10:21:52         stop
```

I'm struggling to calculate time of the trip(mode) for every user, for every day of the month.

My idea was to extract month, day, hour and then group by user, month, day, mode and  hour to calculate the difference between  max and min values using this.

```
df.assign(output=main_table.groupby(['user','month_n','day_n','mode','hour_n']).datetime
                  .apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0]))
```

however when i try summ up the outputs

```
df.groupby(['user','month_n','day_n','mode','hour_n'])['output'].sum()
```

it doesn't seem to produce correct result.

My desired output is

```
  user     month        day        mode        time_spent(sec)
    -------------------------------------------------
    1      10         5         vehicle        3600
    1      10         5         walk           12345
    1      10         5         stop           25879
    1      10         6         walk           15
    1      10         6         vehicle        98522
    2      10         5         walk           1298522
    2      10         11        vehicle        99622
    3      10         6         vehicle        23247
```

Any help will be much much appreciated!! Thanks.

**UPDATED**  a better example of df

```
user    datetime            mode 
 -------------------------------------------------
1   10/09/2015  11:50:27    vehicle
1   10/09/2015  11:50:37    vehicle
1   10/09/2015  11:52:57    vehicle
1   10/09/2015  11:53:27    vehicle
1   10/09/2015  10:21:52    walk
1   10/09/2015  11:52:02    walk
1   10/09/2015  11:53:32    walk
1   10/09/2015  10:23:32    walk
1   10/09/2015  11:50:22    vehicle
1   10/09/2015  11:50:57    vehicle
2   22/11/2015 10:15:53     walk
2   22/11/2015 10:13:53     walk
2   22/11/2015 10:16:08     walk
2   22/11/2015 10:15:38     walk
2   22/11/2015 10:16:23     walk
2   22/11/2015 10:10:33     walk
2   22/11/2015 10:15:03     walk
2   22/11/2015 10:11:13     walk
2   22/11/2015 10:13:08     walk
2   22/11/2015 10:10:28     walk
```

to add some context dataset contains many users, several weeks of datetime and  10 different modes which could be repeated numerous time during the day, each of them have start/end timestamp.

Comment: Can you give an example desired output that is matching your example dataframe? How do you differentiate between a "walk stop" and a "vehicle stop"? If I read your example dataframe correctly the first line is not stopped?

Comment: Why are you using `x.iloc[0]` instead of `x.min()`?  In your sample information `user 1` has no `walk` mode, how does this show up after the `groupby`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I will go:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """user,datetime,mode
1,  10/09/2015  11:50:27,    vehicle
1,  10/09/2015  11:50:37,    vehicle
1,  10/09/2015  11:52:57,    vehicle
1,  10/09/2015  11:53:27,    vehicle
1,  10/09/2015  10:21:52,    walk
1,  10/09/2015  11:52:02,    walk
1,  10/09/2015  11:53:32,    walk
1,  10/09/2015  10:23:32,    walk
1,  10/09/2015  11:50:22,    vehicle
1,  10/09/2015  11:50:57,    vehicle
2,  22/11/2015 10:15:53 ,    walk
2,  22/11/2015 10:13:53 ,    walk
2,  22/11/2015 10:16:08 ,    walk
2,  22/11/2015 10:15:38 ,    walk
2,  22/11/2015 10:16:23 ,    walk
2,  22/11/2015 10:10:33 ,    walk
2,  22/11/2015 10:15:03 ,    walk
2,  22/11/2015 10:11:13 ,    walk
2,  22/11/2015 10:13:08 ,    walk
2,  22/11/2015 10:10:28 ,    walk"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))

df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)

df.groupby(["user", "mode"]).datetime.max() - df.groupby(
    ["user", "mode"]
).datetime.min()
```

It generates the desired output:
[image]